# Split a string into formatted letters for Where IN query

Tags: php, mysql

This is sort of simplistic but I couldnt find anything that works for this particular situation.

Im trying to find a result via a Mysql query where the item in the db is one letter of a string. For example, I have the string 'MYSQL' and I need to retrieve everything in the DB with an identifier of M or and identifier of Q.

So the db looks like this

```
name     identifier
item1      M
item2      Q
item3      B
```

and I want a search for 'MYSQL' to return item1 and item2.

A LIKE doesnt work so I tried a WHERE IN but that doesnt work unless I format the text like 'M','Y','S'...etc

which isnt out of the question but I have a feeling there is a more eloquent way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you insist in implementing it only in MySQL? If you construct the query in PHP, it would be easy

Comment: What does this mean: "a `LIKE` does not work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this string function

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE LOCATE(identifier, "mysql")>0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use REGEXP.

If you create a regular expression with your single character identifier, you can match it to the word you want. For example:

```
select * from TABLENAME
where 'MySQL' REGEXP concat('.*', identifier, '.*');
```

That will get you the rows with 'M' and 'Q' but not the row with 'B'.

Comment: Why a regex? It slows down the query and you just emulate the normal `%` wildcards of the like operator ...

Answer (score 0):

You might be doing your LIKE backwards.

In Oracle flavored syntax, you'd use: `WHERE 'MYSQL' LIKE UPPER('%' || identifier_col || '%')` where `||` is string concatenation and `%` is the wildcard character.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use string concatenation and the `LIKE` operator?

```
SELECT name FROM table_identifiers
    WHERE UCASE('MYSQL') LIKE UCASE(CONCAT('%', identifier, '%'))
```